# how to rewrite url formatting with parameter name in yii

Tags: php, parameters, yii, url-rewriting

i'm very new to Yii, Normally yii serve like this url format

```
baseurl/app_dir/conroller/action/parametername/vaule
```

But i want to show up it like this

```
baseurl/app_dir/conroller/action/vaule
```

means without parameter name.

i read lot of solutions but couldn't find, does anybody knows how to do it, please help me.

Comment: You should read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhere in docs, here is example:

```
'/user/<id:\w+>/' => 'user/view/'
```

This means, that request `/user/someUserName` will be directed to action `view` in controller `user` with parameter `id` with value `someUserName`. This way you have urls with just value, but in application it is available as named `$_GET` parameter.

**NOTE**: `\w+` is just regex, which are supported here, you could for example use `\d+` to limit value to numeric etc.